# Best Python mechanism to allow in order open/close of serial port in multi-threaded program

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, serial-port, locking

I'm working on some legacy Python 2.7 code and I think it has some race conditions.  On the system, the serial port should be opened once, then closed once, then re-opened etc. if needed.

I'm seeing cases of double opens and other mis-matches.  Is there a simple locking mechanism I can add to ensure the open/close happens correctly.

Fred

Comment: Have you heard about [`Lock`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects)s from the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module?

Comment: OK, so it may be as simple as acquiring the lock in the open call, and releasing it in the close call?  That would prevent a double open etc.?

Comment: I've actually never used `threading` so I don't know.

Comment: Can you post a sample runnable piece of code and the error you are getting? I recently wrote a python script for serial data... I can possibly help...